# Search form using sunspot/solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using sunspot for the first time and i'm trying to setup the search. full text search seems to work fine. however, i have a form with a search box and multiple filters on boolean fields that the user can select. somehow the search box works fine but solr isn't picking up the individual booleans as additional filters. also, when i don't do any search text and just want to search by the boolean fields, nothing happens. any help would be appreciated:

this is my controller:

```
@search = Project.search do
   fulltext params[:search]
   facet(:master_bedroom)
   facet(:dining_room)
   facet(:bath)
   with(:master_bedroom, params[:mb]) if params[:mb].present?
   with(:dining_room, params[:dr]) if params[:dr].present?
   with(:bath, params[:p_bath]) if params[:p_bath].present?
 end
```

i have the fields in the model:

```
searchable do
text :description
boolean :dining_room
boolean :bath
boolean :master_bedroom
end
```

and i have the following for my view:

```
<%= form_tag projects_path, :method => :get do %>

<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= check_box_tag :bath, 'true'%>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in variable naming.

Comment: Care to elaborate where this mistake was?

Comment: I've forgotten in the last two years :). i vaguely remember it was misspelling one of the variables. ah, here it is in the code above:    with(:bath, params[:p_bath]) if params[:p_bath].present?  it's using "p_" where my other code doesn't.